# Adding a CASE statement has dramatically increased my query execution time

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have added the following `CASE` statement in my query:

```
CASE starlingYear
    WHEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR, 3000) THEN 'Not yet active'
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, starlingYear)
END AS starBirth
```

Adding this `CASE` has increased the query execution time from less than a second to about 8 or 10 seconds.

The query only has about 1000 rows.

Is there a way to increase performance?

Comment: Where did you add the `CASE` **expression**. What is the full query? Why are you converting `'3000'` to a `varchar`? Is `starlingYear` not an `int`? If so, why not just pass `'3000'`?

Comment: I added it in the middle of the query. `starlingYear` is an `int`. But I need to return the string `Not yet active` if `starlingYear` is `3000`.

Comment: At least one will be if `starlingYear` is an int, due to data type precedence and that `'Not yet active'` isnt' a valid `int` value, @forpas .

Comment: @forpas if I take them out I get this error mesg: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Not yet active' to data type int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax should be as follows. If startlingYear is 3000 (int) then 'Not yet active' else convert starlingYear to varchar.

```
SELECT CASE  starlingYear
    WHEN 3000 
       THEN 'Not yet active'
    ELSE 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), starlingYear) 
    END AS starBirth
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or above, you could use the following, as well.  There's no advantage in performance as it resolves to a Case statement much like what jose_bacoy posted but some prefer the condensed format of the IIF operator.

```
 SELECT starBirth = IIF(starlingYear = 3000,'Not yet active',CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),starlingyear)
   FROM dbo.table1
;
```

Note that IIF is only useful for a single condition unless you nest it, but that can get a bit ugly.